# Custom tags in CKEditor BBCode plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, ckeditor, bbcode

I'm using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) with [BBCode plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/bbcode) and I need to add custom tags like a `spoiler` tag and another one which would provide the possibility to link to a site user's profile.
`spoiler` tags would work like `blockquote` tags: clicking the button and getting the code. I copied `blockquote/plugin.js` and changed all `blockquote` strings to `spoiler` and `quote` to `spoil`. Then I added `extraPlugins: 'spoiler'` to the configuration and a button on the toolbar. It appears correctly, but it generates a wrong code.
For example, if I click the blockquote button after selecting a text, the following code gets generated:

```
[quote]some text[/quote]
```

but when I click my new button, I get the following code:

```
<p>
    <spoiler>
    <p>
        !!!</p>
    </spoiler></p>
```

So it doesn't work.

I would also like to create a button for linking to a user. It should work like this: after clicking the button, a dialog would show up with a search field (AJAX is not a problem), and the result would be a list of users; when a user would be chosen and the `OK` button would be clicked, it would generate a code like the following:

```
[user=1]Admin[/user]
```

1 - id of user, Admin - his name.

Comment: Which version of CKEditor are you using?

Comment: You most likely want to edit [`plugins/bbcode/plugin.js`](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/bbcode/plugin.js).

There are two variables there, bbcodeMap and convertMap. This plugin turns HTML into BBCode, so you will want to add a new definition for your `spoiler` tag.

Answer (score -2):

I had many problems with CKEditor. I'm using WYSIWYG Froala. He probably solve your problems.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).